# Problem with cross compiling icu

Tags: iphone, cross-compiling, icu

I am trying to cross compile the icu library for the iPhone. I downloaded a configure script wrapper from http://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/coding/articles/iphone
When I execute it, I get the following error message:

```
checking wchar.h usability... no
checking wchar.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: wchar.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: wchar.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: wchar.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: wchar.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: wchar.h: proceeding with the preprocessor's result
configure: WARNING: wchar.h: in the future, the compiler will take precedence
checking for wchar.h... yes
checking for library containing wcscpy... none required
checking size of wchar_t... 0
configure: error: There is wchar.h but the size of wchar_t is 0
```

Does anyone have a clue how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This problem is present when compiling the ICU library for Android in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I made a very dirty hack to solve the problem: I just removed this check in the configure script. Then, icu compiled. Hope now, that it also works correctly...

Comment: Hrmmm. What does config.log say? Maybe you should file a bug against ICU.

Comment: configure:7373: result: 0
configure:7387: error: There is wchar.h but the size of wchar_t is 0

Comment: If you'd like to make it an undirty hack you could submit it.

Answer (score 0):

in the platform.h you must define the size of wchar_t to the size of the actual platform. If you dont do this it does not work.

## define U_SIZEOF_WCHAR_T 4 // macosx

Manfred

Comment: I use the length of 4 for iphone too