# Compiling ICU using arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3

Tags: android, configure, icu

I would like to cross-compile ICU static libs for Android using Cygwin. So far, I have been able to configure and make the Cygwin/MSVC and Cygwin versions. I have installed the android-ndk-r7 and can see a version of gcc in the toolchains directory. Several examples suggest using host:arm-eabi - but this is not present on my machine.

I have copied *mh-linux* to *mh-unknown* in */icu/source/config* and run the following:

```
export HOST_ICU=/cygdrive/d/__/External/SQLite/icu
export ICU_CROSS_BUILD=/cygdrive/d/__/External/SQLite/icu-cygwin
export NDK_ROOT=/cygdrive/d/__/android-ndk-r7
export CPPFLAGS="-I$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/ -O3 -fno-short-wchar -DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0 -DU_GNUC_UTF16_STRING=0 -fno-short-enums -nostdlib"
export CXXFLAGS="-I$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/ -O3 -fno-short-wchar -DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0 -DU_GNUC_UTF16_STRING=0 -fno-short-enums -nostdlib"
export CFLAGS="-I$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/ -O3 -fno-short-wchar -DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0 -DU_GNUC_UTF16_STRING=0 -fno-short-enums -nostdlib"
export LDFLAGS="-lc -Wl,-rpath-link=$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/ -L $NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/"

$HOST_ICU/source/configure --with-cross-build=$ICU_CROSS_BUILD --enable-extras=no --enable-strict=no --enable-static --enable-shared=no --enable-tests=no --enable-samples=no --enable-dyload=no --enable-tools=no --host=arm-eabi --with-data-packaging=archive
```

I get the following error:

```
checking for ICU version numbers... release 4.8.1.1, library 48.1.1, unicode version 6.0
checking build system type... i686-pc-cygwin
checking host system type... arm-unknown-eabi
checking target system type... arm-unknown-eabi
checking whether to build debug libraries... no
checking whether to build release libraries... yes
checking for arm-eabi-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/cygdrive/d/Projects/__/External/SQLite/icu-android':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I'm sure this is a "stupid" question, but how do I get the ICU configure script to point to the gcc under $NDK_ROOT\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3\prebuilt\windows\arm-linux-androideabi\bin? Am I missing some setup or install? Should I be setting my PATH so that the first *gcc* found is the one in *arm-linux-androiedeabi*?

**Update 1.** I just noticed that while *windows\arm-linux=androideabi\bin* contains *gcc*, *windows\bin* contains *arm-linux-androideabi-gcc*. How do I get ICU to call this?

**Update 2.** On the suggestion of Steven R. Loomis, I picked up updates for config.sub and config.guess from

> http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.sub;hb=HEAD
>   http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.guess;hb=HEAD

placed *android-ndk-r7/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin* into my path, and re-ran configure with --host=arm-linux-androideabi... this time:

```
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
```

Definitely closer. Detailed error from config.log

```
gcc version 4.4.3 (GCC)
configure:3125: $? = 0
configure:3114: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -V >&5
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe: '-V' option must have argument
configure:3125: $? = 1
configure:3114: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -qversion >&5
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe: unrecognized option '-qversion'
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe: no input files
configure:3125: $? = 1
configure:3145: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3167: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -I/cygdrive/d/Projects/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include
/ -O3 -fno-short-wchar -DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0 -DU_GNUC_UTF16_STRING=0 -fno-short-enums -nostdlib -I/cygdrive/d/Projec
ts/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/ -O3 -fno-short-wchar -DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0 -DU_GNUC_UTF1
6_STRING=0 -fno-short-enums -nostdlib -lc -Wl,-rpath-link=/cygdrive/d/Projects/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-a
rm/usr/lib/ -L /cygdrive/d/Projects/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/ conftest.c  >&5
D:/Projects/android-ndk-r7/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/
4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3171: $? = 1
configure:3209: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| int
| main ()
| {
|
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3214: error: in `/cygdrive/d/Projects/__/External/SQLITE/icu-android':
configure:3216: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

**Update 3.** The changes to config.sub and config.guess worked in that we are now using the right gcc compiler. The -lc failure comes from not being able to find libc.so (which is in android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib" even though this is in the LDFLAGS.  I did have an extra space after -L in the original LDFLAGS, but removing this did not help.

**Update 4.** According to an older post in http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/46295616a889bc12

> "The windows ndk toolchain is (thankfully) native to windows, so it
>   doesnt go  through the cygwin translation layer which would translate
>   /cygdrive paths."

**Update 5.** Swapped all instances of /cygdrive/d/ with D:/. Now C compiler works though it still doesn't make. Suspect that ICU_CROSS_BUILD has to be in the icu/source directory.

```
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether arm-linux-androideabi-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-g++... arm-linux-androideabi-g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether arm-linux-androideabi-g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -E
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for gmake... /usr/bin/gmake
configure: error: D:/Projects/__/External/SQLite/icu-cygwin/config/icucross.mk not found. Please build ICU in
 D:/Projects/__/External/SQLite/icu-cygwin first.
```

**Update 6.** I re-configured and rbuilt my Cygwin folder in icu-cygwin. Go figure, this time icucross.mk was there. Successful configuration! But...

**Update 7** **Make** did not end up so well.

```
$ make
D:/Projects/__/External/SQLite/icu/source/config/mh-linux:41: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.
```

What?!?! It seems that now we want Cygwin paths again.. :(

**Update 8.** Changed my paths so that HOST_ICU and ICU_CROSS_BUILD use Cygwin paths, but NDK_ROOT is Windows path (since Android NDK ld can't handle cygwin paths).

THis time further but

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe: /cygdrive/d/Projects/__/External/SQLit                                                                 e/icu/source/stubdata/stubdata.c: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe: no input files
```

Seems that what has to happen is that arm-linux-androideabi-gcc needs to be made for cygwin, or the cross-build will not work.

**Update 9.** It seems that arm-linux-androideabi-gcc does not support cygwin paths - though ndk_build does. However, ICU is set to call arm-linux-androideabi-gcc while "make" requires cygwin paths. Maybe time to switch to OSX or Linux to do this.

**Update 10 - Still no success.** 
*Cygwin* - Apparently the arm-linux-androideabi Crystax build also doesn't support cygwin paths in -L. Attempting to cross-compile under Cygwin will give the -lc error, since it cannot parse the -L/cygdrive/d/... path to the library. Changing to D:/ helps, but later causes make to fail since it is Cygwin make.

*Linux* - Using the normal NDK r7 build, configuration will fail with a wchar_t = 0 error. The Crystax NDK build will fix this, and make will fail complaining about uint64_t in Android's sys/type.h. See [ICU library in Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168962/icu-library-in-android-ndk/9224077#9224077). You can force it to be defined and it will lead to yet another error about size mismatch.

*OSX* - Probably the most successful, compiling using the official build or the Crystax build, it leads directly to the uint64_t bug. If you hack around it, it will lead you to

```
icu/source/common/ustrenum.cpp:118: error: must #include <typeinfo> before using typeid
```

Help!

Comment: i am taking a jab here. You are missing a library. Seems like your C compiler cant build for target architecture. outdated build script etc.

Comment: @Vangel At this point it is exactly that. arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is looking for -lc (libc.so) which is in /cygdrive/d/Projects/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/lib/ (which is specified with -L) but somehow can't find it. Trying to replicate outside of the script, but not sure where to find conftest.c

Comment: Could it be that arm-linux-androideabi-gcc cannot understand cygwin paths?

Comment: That's the case, replacing /cygdrive/d/ with D:/ fixes the problem

Comment: @StevenR.Loomis I spoke too soon.

Comment: I suspect 'make' does not like the colon.

Comment: @tofutim please stop sending me e-mail- discuss it here and/or on the mailing lists.. thanks..

Comment: As a general comment, switching to Linux does not yield immediate goodness. This time the error is "There is wchar.h but the size of wchar_t is 0" similar to the error cited here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395569/problem-with-cross-compiling-icu

Comment: there would be better help over at android dev group I suppose. Or even the IRC channel

Comment: In MacOSX, configure works but makes fails on 'uint64_t' does not name a type in types.h:124. Sigh.

Comment: @StevenR.Loomis Still not working - in either Cygwin, Linux or OSX. OSX seems to go the farthest immediately.

Comment: @tofutim I am not that familiar with android or NDK, but a quick search found http://www.crystax.net/android/ndk-r4.php which says ".. support for RTTI added". That sounds a bit ... suspicious.  ICU will fail without RTTI. It's needed. Does the standard compiler not support RTTI? That's a problem.

Comment: I've tried both to no avail. I doctored by ptypes.h here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247151/compiling-icu-for-android-uint64-t-does-not-name-a-type but I'm not sure of the implications. Next bug is the <typeinfo> which seems included but not sure why there is that error.

Comment: I'm back here again for 49.1.2.

Answer (score 4):

**00.** Download android ndk http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

example `install d:\android-r9b`

**01.** Download install example `d:\msys MSys` http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS 1.01

**02.** Download gcc 3.8.1 w64 http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/ example install `d:\mingw32_64`

**03.** Download icu versin 52.1 http://site.icu-project.org/download/52#TOC-ICU4C-Download

**04.** Extract icu source code to `d:\icu`

**05.** Enter `msys`  use `export PATH=/d/msys/1.0/bin:/d/ming32_64/mingw32/bin:$PATH`

**06.** `cd /d/icu;mkdir mingw;mkdir android;cd mingw`

this is follow icu readme.html cross compile steps

**07.** `cd /d/icu/ming ;../source/runConfigureICU MinGW ;make`

no problem,all is working and under `/d/icu/mingw/bin` generate tools for cross compile later.

**08.** `cd /d/icu/android`

**09.** `/d/android-ndk-r9b/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-9 --install-dir=/d/androidgcc/ -- toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.8`

if use window 7/8 64bit add additional options: --`system=windowx86_64`

**10.** export `PATH` again;    `export PATH=/d/msys/1.0/bin/:/d/androidgcc/bin/:/d/androidgcc/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/`

the path must include the `ar.exe` execute for create library.

**11.** create shared library.

```
sh ../source/configure --host=armv6-google-linux --enable-shared=yes --disable-static -with-cross-build=/d/icu/mingw CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc CXX=arm-linux-androideabi-g++ AR=arm-linux-androideabi-ar --with-data-packaging=archive
```

**12.** `make`

all is successful

Comment: anyway,if has error can't find langinfo.h error.
you could download it from:
http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/OpenBSD/src/include/ download langinfo.hand nl_types.h save to /d/ic/source/common

Comment: Since this is your first answer, please observe my edit to see how to answer properly. Welcome to SO and Happy Coding !!!

Comment: These steps were very helpful. I had to add ```RANLIB=arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib``` to step 11 to get it to build successfully however.